# How to do a cfdump inside a cfscript tag?

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfml, openbd

In order to debug I would like to dump certain variables on to my web page. How can I do that from inside a cfscript tag?

I tried the following but it isn't working:

```
<cfscript>
  ...
  <cfif cgi.REMOTE_ADDR eq "IP">
    <cfdump var="#var1#"><br/>
  </cfif>
  ...
</cfscript>
```

Any clues on what can be done?

Comment: Strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917706/cfdump-cfcomponent-cfscript/1917756

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can't do it directly like that in versions before CF 9. You can, however, use the [dump()](http://cflib.org/udf/Dump) UDF found at CFLib. There's a whole library of UDFs there that mimic CF tags that don't have direct CFSCRIPT equivalents.

ColdFusion 9 (and up) offers the `writeDump()` function.

Adobe Documentation Linkfor [WriteDump()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/writedump.html) function

Answer (score 32):

use writeDump() like how you use writeOutput()

see [writeDump](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/writedump.html) on CF 9 reference

Answer (score 5):

Isn't the following much easier and straightforward?

```
oAdmin = createObject("component", "cfide.adminapi.base");
oAdmin.dump(myVar);
```

It works on CF7 and forward, perhaps even earlier.

Answer (score 3):

It would be fairly easy to write your own too. You just define a function in cfml rather than cfscript. You can use this to do cfaborts and cfloops as well.

Something like this (Off the top of my head...not executed).

```
<CFFUNCTION NAME="MyDump">
    <CFARGUMENT NAME="OBJ" Required="TRUE">
    <CFDUMP VAR="#Obj#">
</CFFUNCTION>
<CFSCRIPT>
  if(cgi.REMOTE_ADDR eq "IP"){
    MyDump(Var1);
  }
</CFSCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 3):

Now plain tag names allowed within cfscript starting ColdFusion 11

```
<cfscript>
    cfdump (var=#myVar#);
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<cffunction name="setAbort" access="private" returntype="void" output="false">
 <cfdump var="#arguments#"/><cfabort>
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score -1):

For dump we use Writedump(myvar); instead of  in cfscript and same we use abort; instead of  for exit the execution of program at any instance.we use writeoutput(); instead of

```
 <cfoutput>#myvar#</cfoutput>
```

below is the code for dump and abort in cfscript.

```
writedump(myvar); for dump

abort; for stop execution of programm 

writeoutput(myvar); for output within cfscript
```