# CFdump cfcomponent cfscript

Tags: coldfusion

Can one use cfdump inside a cfcomponent?
Can one use cfdump inside a cfscript?

I know the anser is no then how can one emit the values of the functions insde cfcomponent
cfscript?
I am using CF8

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a cfdump inside a cfscript tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883585/how-to-do-a-cfdump-inside-a-cfscript-tag)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can one use cfdump inside a cfcomponent?

Yes, with some caveats. If you use a CFDUMP followed by CFABORT, the dump will be displayed whether or not the component/method has output turned off. That does, of course, abort all processing.

> Can one use cfdump inside a cfscript?

Not exactly (unless you're using CF9), but there are workarounds.

You can close your script, put in the dump tag, then re-open it, like so:

```
</cfscript><cfdump var="#myVar#"><cfscript>
```

There is also a UDF at CFLib that mimics the CFDUMP tag.

[Dump](http://cflib.org/udf/Dump)

Added: In CF9 or later, there is also [writeDump()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS5A998FA0-0173-4be8-9548-680E8F40A5F2.html).

Comment: Yes, of course. But I don't have CF9 here and was in the middle of looking it up in the CFML reference. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Coldfusion 9:

```
<cfscript>
    myVar = "this is a test";
    WriteDump(myVar); 
</cfscript>
```

Coldfusion 8 and below:
CF 8 does not have a cfscript version of the  tag, so if needed, it needs to be abstracted into a user defined function first. This function will need to be accessible to your component.

I avoided the name "WriteDump()" to prevent any possible conflict if this code is used with CF9.

```
<!--- Abstract cfdump tag for use in cfscript --->
<cffunction name="scriptDump" output="no" hint="Abstracts cfdump for cfscript">
    <cfargument name="myVar" required="yes">
    <cfset var result = "">

    <cfsavecontent variable="result">
        <cfdump var="#arguments.myVar#">
    </cfsavecontent>

    <cfreturn result>
</cffunction>

<cfset myVar = "this is a test">

<!--- Test the scriptDump(var) function in cfscript --->
<cfscript>
    dumpOfMyVar = scriptDump(myVar);
</cfscript>

<!--- Test the scriptDump(var) function in regular HTML --->
<cfoutput>
    #scriptDump(myVar)#
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

cfdump inside cfcomponent? why not... But I think you should do it in a cffunction.

cfdump inside cfscript? WriteDump() in CF9, or search cflib for a UDF that works in CF6+

Answer (score 1):

You can only use writeDump in CF9. If you're in CF8, use this:

```
adminapi = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.base");
adminapi.dump(foo);
```